# What's the reasoning behind picking the API's for a certain .NET Platform Standard version?

Tags: .net, .net-core

As I've understood the .NET Platform Standard is a way to provide a contract to support different platforms. So instead of writing a code that should run platforms A, B and C, we target the .NET Platform Standard version supported simultaneously by the three platforms.

The motivation to that as I know, is that each platform has a "base library" available (like the BCL). In the end our code depends on that base library, so we need to know which API's ara available. Targetting platforms A, B and C allows us to know we have access to the API's which are simultaneously available in the base libraries of platforms A, B and C.

The obvious drawback of choosing specific platforms A, B and C is that if another platform appears which also has in its base libraries the API's we need, we can't use it.

With the .NET Platform Standard we target a specific "level of .NET" and thus we have support for platforms which conform to that standard. This is in the sense that we are assured that for that specific .NET Platform Standard we have a certain set of API's which will be present in the platform base libraries.

My point here is: there is one mapping here from platform versions to collections of API's. So for .NET Standard 1.0 we associate a certain list of API's, for .NET Standard 1.1 we associate the same list we had in 1.1 plus more API's and so forth up to 1.4.

In that case we are picking, for each .NET Standard version a list of API's. That being said, a single number is holding a lot of information.

What's the reasoning behind this? How can this single number hold so much information? What defines which API's are supported in each .NET Standard Platform level?

Comment: It is just a version number of the specification.  No different from, say, C# version 5 vs version 6, the number refers the language specification edition.  A group of people decides what is added in each revision, surely driven by the CoreFx team when they decide what to work on next.  With input from partners, surely Xamarin is heavily involved since they are the primary beneficiary.

Comment: I understand that. It is an internal decision to label a set of API's as they want. But what if there is a platform which has some API's which are in the version 1.0 and some which are in the version 1.2 for example? I mean, what if there's a platform whose base library is not any of these particular combination of API's which got labeled?

Comment: You will only get a warranty when you limit yourself to the version number that is implemented by the platform.  Sure, maybe it implements more and it almost always does.  But those types or methods do not appear in the reference assemblies so you can't use them.  Exact same scenario as PCL, minus the permutation explosion.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to PCL, the Platform Standard tries to solve the compatibility issues in a new approach where we assume the 1.0 release matches a few platforms (though in fact such platforms were not released with such a standard in mind). Then some new APIs are added in the 2.0 release, so the matching platforms get upgraded.

So the current mapping of all existing platforms to the standard platform releases is just like making up a history of how such platforms were "designed and released".

It emphasizes more about how in the future the .NET ecosystem should be governed.

For example, if Microsoft and Xamarin (as well as other major vendors) would like to release a new standard platform version (the specification), then they can discuss what are the new APIs to be added. After that each vendors must ship their new platforms (.NET Framework/.NET Core/Xamarin.iOS and so on) to match the new standard. Otherwise, they will lose their position in the ecosystem.

Other programming languages such as C++ have been using this approach for years and it works. Check out C++ 11, C++ 14 and C++ 17.

Comment: Quoting a language that has notoriously poor library support might not be the best way to make your point ;)

Comment: Interesting that on Build 2016 the BCL guys rename .NET Platform Standard to .NET Standard Library, and they do choose a term with C/C++ legacy.